# Regex to match price in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I tried to catch price with python but my regex returns nothing.

The sentence is : "Word1 WordA WordB WordC ... WordX : Price €". we know the Word1 but we don't know Word A to X neither the Price (4 digits with "," "." or nothing between 1st and 2nd digits).

**we need to get the Price number just before the "€" which is following Word1...**

I've created this :

```
regex = "(Word1) ([a-zA-Z])+ ( :)? ([0-9]{0,4})+ €"
```

Which matches on :

> Word1 zerdezd : 1243 €

> Word1 zerdezd 1243 €

But not on

> Word1 zerdezd ezrozeu : 1243 €

And this doesn't work...

```
(Charges) (([a-zA-Z])+ )+( :){0,1} ([0-9]{0,4})+ €
```

Comment: Why not just `\bWord1 .*?\b([0-9]{1,4}(?:[.,]\d+)?) €` https://regex101.com/r/A0t1ww/1

Comment: It seems to be pretty good, thx !

Comment: The question shows a tried pattern, a description of the data, example data and in bold the desired result. IMHO the question seems clear to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match Word followed by as least as possible characters until you can capture the amount in group 1 that is followed by a euro sign.

```
\bWord1 .*?\b([0-9]{1,4}(?:[.,]\d+)?) €
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bWord1 .*?` Match Word followed by a space and as least as possible chars
- `\b(` Word boundary, start **group 1**

  - `[0-9]{1,4}(?:[.,]\d+)?` Match 1-4 digits with an optional decimal part
- `)` Close group 1
- `€` Match literally (or use `\s*€` if there can be 0 or more whitespace chars)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A0t1ww/1)

Example

```
import re
 
regex = r"\bWord1 .*?\b([0-9]{1,4}(?:[.,]\d+)?) €"
 
s = ("Word1 zerdezd : 1243 €\n"
    "Word1 zerdezd 1243 €\n"
    "Word1 zerdezd ezrozeu : 1243 €")
print(re.findall(regex, s))
```

Output

```
['1243', '1243', '1243']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/yCcCDk)

Comment: Thanks, how to extract the 1234 number with python then please ?

Comment: @taki I have added an example with re.findall. You could also use re.search and get the group 1 value

Comment: Thanks a lot that's working great ! Do you know a way to also match if the "€" sign is  "euros" please ? with (€|euros) ?

Comment: @taki You can include it in the capture group https://regex101.com/r/fcIMb0/1

Comment: I see, with just €|euros without ( )

Comment: @taki (Note that from 15 reputation points you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)) the answers that you consider useful.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Word1\s.*?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)\s*(?:€|euro)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/53YYlf/4).

In Python:

```py
rx = r'Word1\s.*?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)\s*(?:€|euro)'
m = re.search(rx, text)
if m:
  print(m.group(1)) # prints the price

# or
print(re.findall(rx, text))
```

Comment: Thx but it doesnt matches with Word1 zerdezd ezrozeu : 1243 €

Comment: @taki Now it does. Next time please do not write "but not on", it is not clear, it sounds as if you do not want to match it.

Comment: @taki I added a Python snippet, too.

Comment: @taki The regex may be simplified to `Word1\s.*?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?)\s*€` if you need the first float/int from `Word1` and do not need the rest.

Comment: @taki You can't imagine how it is difficult to type on a mini notebook...

Comment: I did it on a smartphone a while ago copy pasting stuff...omg. Here is my 1+ :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird I type faster on a smartphone, but it is occupied by my kid :(